# how to join query different table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to join three tables which are named attendances, categories, and users.
my code is

```
 $Attendance= DB::table('users')
     ->join('categories','users.U_category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
     ->select('users.*','categories.batch_name')->get();
```

but I also need to join attendances table where attendances column User_A_ID and users table id are the same. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with

```
$Attendance= DB::table('users')
            ->join('categories','users.U_category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->join('attendances','users.id', '=', 'attendances.User_A_ID')
            ->select('users.*','categories.batch_name')->get();
```